# Function to Combine Several Pandas Series into a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe of financial values (`df_price`). I compute moving averages on one of the dataframe's columns/series (using a simple function, `MA`), and then I create a new dataframe (`df_indicators`), which contains each of the moving averages as a column/series.

I have to do this same basic operation repeatedly for many different indicators and dataframes so I'd like to create a function (call it `bundle_indicators`) to do it.

Basically, I'd like to call `bundle_indicators` with three arguments:

1. A list of the indicator names,
2. a list (or series) of values for each of the indicators,
3. `df_price` so that `bundle_indicators` can use it's index when creating the dataframe.

I'd like `bundle_indicators` to return a dataframe with each of the columns/series named after one of the indicators and each row/index representing that indicator's value.

Below is how I currently do it. It runs without errors but I'd like to replace the last paragraph with a function. I've tried everything I can think of but get errors, usually related to passing the arguments. I'd really appreciate anyone's help as I've been at this for quite a while now.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# Create a new dataframe
df_price = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['1993.01.29', '1993.02.01', '1993.02.02', '1993.02.03', '1993.02.04', '1993.02.05', '1993.02.08', '1993.02.09', '1993.02.10', '1993.02.11'], 
    'Open': [43.80, 43.80, 44.05, 44.17, 44.67, 43.80, 44.05, 44.17, 44.67, 44.92], 
    'High': [43.80, 44.05, 44.17, 44.67, 44.92, 43.80, 43.80, 44.05, 44.17, 44.67], 
    'Low': [43.55, 43.80, 43.92, 44.17, 44.55, 43.80, 44.05, 44.17, 44.55, 44.89], 
    'Close': [43.80, 44.05, 44.17, 44.55, 44.89, 43.55, 43.80, 43.92, 44.17, 44.55],
    'Volume': [1007786, 482696, 202220, 531820, 533930, 1007786, 482696, 202220, 531820, 533930]
})


# Moving Average funtion
def MA(lb, frame):
    prices = frame['Close']
    mavg = []

    for i in range(len(prices)):
        if i < lb:
            mavg.append(0)
        else:
            sum_array = prices[(i - lb): (i + 1)] 
            mavg.append(np.mean(sum_array))
    return mavg


# Calculate the moving average for three different lookback periods: 1, 2, 4
mavg_fast = MA(1, df_price)
mavg_med = MA(2, df_price)
mavg_slow = MA(4, df_price)

# Create a new df_indicators dataframe, using df_price's index
# TODO REPLACE THIS WITH A FUNCTION THAT RETURNS A DATAFRAME 
df_indicators = pd.DataFrame({'mavg_fast': mavg_fast}, index = df_price.index)
df_indicators = df_indicators.assign(mavg_med= mavg_med)
df_indicators = df_indicators.assign(mavg_slow = mavg_slow)

print(df_indicators)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building your dataframe with a dictionary comprehension to be passed into `DataFrame()` call where you iterate through the *indicators name* and *values list* elementwise with `zip` and map keys and values to migrate as columns and rows:

```
def bundle_indicators(indicators_name, values_list, df):        
    output = pd.DataFrame({k:v for k,v in zip(indicators_name, values_list)},
                          index=df.index)        
    return output

df_indicators_new = bundle_indicators(['mavg_fast', 'mavg_med', 'mavg_slow'],
                                      [mavg_fast, mavg_med, mavg_slow],
                                      df_price)

print(df_indicators_new)
#    mavg_fast   mavg_med  mavg_slow
# 0      0.000   0.000000      0.000
# 1     43.925   0.000000      0.000
# 2     44.110  44.006667      0.000
# 3     44.360  44.256667      0.000
# 4     44.720  44.536667     44.292
# 5     44.220  44.330000     44.242
# 6     43.675  44.080000     44.192
# 7     43.860  43.756667     44.142
# 8     44.045  43.963333     44.066
# 9     44.360  44.213333     43.998

# COMPARISON WITH ORIGINAL OUTPUT
print(df_indicators.eq(df_indicators_new))
#    mavg_fast  mavg_med  mavg_slow
# 0       True      True       True
# 1       True      True       True
# 2       True      True       True
# 3       True      True       True
# 4       True      True       True
# 5       True      True       True
# 6       True      True       True
# 7       True      True       True
# 8       True      True       True
# 9       True      True       True
```

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I needed. Super elegant solution! Thanks so much for taking the time to respond. I tried to upvote your answer but stacko says that my vote doesn't display because my reputation score isn't > 15, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help on your interesting question. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you end up with a list of values the same length as the dataframe. You can assign these values as a new column in the dataframe by simply doing `df_price['new_column']=list_of_values`
This might be what you require.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but that's not quite what I'm looking to do. In the code above, I'm already able to create a new dataframe and columns within it to hold all of the indicator values (note: I don't want them in `df_price` so I put them in their own dataframe `df_indicators`). What I want is a function that performs the last three lines of code for N number of indicators and returns `df_indicators`.